# Instance member 'rawValue' cannot be used on type 'MessageComposeResult'

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, migration, xcode8

I am a beginner Swift developer migrating my app to to swift 3 and I can't fix this error message.
Instance member 'rawValue' cannot be used on type 'MessageComposeResult'
Do you have any idea what is wrong with my code?
Thanks a lot for your help

```
    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    if result.rawValue == MessageComposeResult.rawValue {
        print("Invitation SMS sent successfully")
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your if statement with this:

```
if result == MessageComposeResult.sent {

}
```

You cannot check rawValue on MessageComposeResult because rawValue is an instance member. In other words, it is only available on instances of MessageComposeResult (like your `result` variable) and not on the MessageComposeResult type itself.